# Can an event fire while you are inside of subroutine?

Tags: excel, vba

I realize that my algo to move the image is a mess, but that is unimportant right now. My question really revolves around the following - is it possible to set this up such that when I double click the dblclick event fires, changing doubleClicked to false and then exiting my loop?

```
Dim orginx As Long
Dim originy As Long
Dim doubleClicked As Boolean

Private Sub Image1_Click()
    doubleClicked = False

    originx = Image1.Left
    originy = Image1.Top

    Do
    If originx / 2 > 1 Then
        Do
        Image1.Left = originx - 2
        Image1.Top = originy - 2
        originx = Image1.Left
        originy = Image1.Top
        Loop Until originx / 2 < 1
    Else
        Do
        Image1.Left = originx + 2
        Image1.Top = originy + 2
        originx = Image1.Left
        originy = Image1.Top
        Loop Until originx + 2 > 432
    End If
    Loop Until doubleClicked = True
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    doubleClicked = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `doubleClicked = False` - did you mean to set this to `True` in the double-click handler?

Comment: @TimWilliams good catch thank you. when testing i put a stop inside of that sub so i know it doesnt fire, but if it did it wouldntve worked lol. edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need to add a DoEvents() in your do loop (anywhere will do), but this will come with a performance penalty.